# How to customize default tab in Eclipse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

I search by files often in Eclipse. Is it possible for the "File Search" tab to be opened by default when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>?

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: it's Windows 7 OS

Comment: A few good answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/91984/1546513

Answer (score 3):

You can define a key sequence to File Search.

- Select Window > Preferences
- Select General > Keys
- Scroll down to the
  File Search command
- Click in the Binding field
- Press the key sequence
  you want to use for File Search - I used Ctrl-Alt-F because it was
  unused. Alternatively you could use Ctrl-H and unbind it from Open Search Dialog
- Click OK